# oh-my-zsh config file not loading

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I am trying to get ZSH config working correctly on Mac OSX. I installed it using curl: `curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh`. Then I modified my zshrc file to fit my needs. It works only after I run `source ~/.zshrc`. But then if I come back and open a new tab or new terminal I have to do `source ~/.zshrc` to get the config settings to work again. Has anybody ran into this issue? I believe there is a way to make it so I don't have to do source `~/.zshrc` with every new tab.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the machine. I just got a new Mac and have this issue now. I also run Linux Mint and have the same issue. All of it works after running source ~/.zshrc so if I can get that config to load on login it would fix it.

Comment: Restarting should not be necessary, but often login and just opening a new terminal can be different. I am running out of ideas, but the one thing you could try is see if the env. variable ZDOTDIR is set (e.g. in `/etc/zshenv`), if that is set it determines from where .zshrc is read, and only if **not** set it takes ~/.zshrc . Also see [zsh manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh) (It has been a while since I used `zsh`)

Comment: `zsh` on Mac OS X should work without requiring you to `source ~/.zshrc` so I'll ask a possibly stupid question: have you set your shell to `zsh` (default is `bash`)?

Comment: Yes my default shell is zsh it loads the zsh prompt when I open the terminal or a new tab.

Answer (score 41):

I figured this out. It was due to my config file. The part of the zsh config that wasn't loading needed to be moved down after the plugins load. After moving that it all worked as expected.

Comment: could you give some more details? I'm having the same probvlem

Comment: What is your specific issue? I had to move some of my custom codings below the plugins= line source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward

autoload -U edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line   That fixed it for me

Comment: Cool. I've finally found the problem, somehow plugins and loading oh-my-zsh became swapped. The correct order for reference: `plugins=(osx git )` then `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: More generally, _any_ oh-my-zsh config needs to be loaded before sourcing `$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Comment: @AndrewHundt your comment was the exact solution in my case. It just feels unnatural for the plugins to be called first and then OMZSH to be sourced!

Answer (score 30):

If you have themes like Powerlevel9k installed for your `zsh` shell then source the oh-my-zsh config file **after** the theme variable assignments in your `.zshrc` file like shown below.

**Eg:**

```
........
........
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=('status' 'load' 'ram_joined' 'time')

# source oh-my-zsh config
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: I tried all the above solutions but I was still facing the problem. This Solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This was what I needed as well!

Comment: This is perfect. Saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Not the ideal solution but solves the issue:

Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Shells -> Startup

Check the box that says "Run command" and in the input box run

```
source ~/.zsh/.zshrc
```

This will be executed when you open a new terminal window / tab.

Comment: changing the Shells Open with option is a better Idea.
 - Open Preferences for Terminal
 - Select the General Tab
 - Change Sells open with from Default login shell to Command (complete path) with the /bin/zsh in the input box.

Answer (score 7):

My final solution was to go to *Terminal --> Preferences --> General --> Shells open with --> Command (complete path)*, and set it to /bin/zsh (or your path to zsh), and then set both New windows/tabs open with to *"Same profile"*. It works fine for me.

My initial attempt was to go to *Terminal --> Preferences --> Profiles*, and in my default profile's *"shell" tab's Startup section*, I set it to run command "source ~/.zshrc". This also solved the problem of /.zshrc not loading, but it seemed tedious to see that command show on every terminal tab/window.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I found that I had long ago changed my Terminal preferences to run tcsh instead of the default login shell.  Took me forever to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

On mac zsh it is loading ~/.zsh_profile on shell start. So just create one like this will do.

`echo "source ~/.zshrc" > .zsh_profile`

Or just put your .zshrc content into .zsh_profile. Whatever works for you.

Comment: I would just create a symlink to the file so when you edit one file the other is updated too (it points to the first one).. no double-edit is required in that case :-)
```ln -s ~/.zshrc ~/.zsh_profile```