# oh-my-zsh not applying themes

Tags: oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I just set up `zsh` together with `oh-my-zsh`. But there's a bit of strange behavior that I cannot understand. If I restart Terminal (or iTerm 2––the behavior is the same in either) the theme specified in `~/.zshrc` is not loaded. I need to do `source ~/.zshrc` for it to happen. If I `echo $ZSH_THEME` I get the theme I specified in `~/.zshrc`. (And if I add `echo "I'm loading it."` to the bottom of `~/.zshrc`, for example, I get the expected message upon opening a new window, etc.)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682456/oh-my-zsh-config-file-not-loading) is very similar to mine. But none of the suggestions there appear relevant: the problem there was that some bits of `~/.zshrc` were not being loaded, whereas in my case it seems they are being 'read' but not 'loaded' if that's a thing.

In case this is relevant: I do not have any files named `.zprofile` or `.profile` in my home directory.

Another bit of relevant information. If I change the value of `ZSH_THEME` in my `.zshrc` file, I need to source it twice in order to activate the new theme.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Posting here in case it helps others. The problem was that I was loading the theme after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`, so clearly `oh-my-zsh` wasn't loading it. (The instructions in the `.zshrc` template generated by `oh-my-zsh` are a little confusing. On a quick read they suggest that themes should be loaded below the `User configuration` line.)

Comment: it works after I put the customized theme in the bottom of the setting.

Comment: OMG thank you. I went like 15 backups back and couldn't find the issue... it turns out I accidentally moved the theme command below oh-my-zsh `source` command immediately after installing it.

Comment: Put the "source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh" in the EOF .zshrc

Comment: @omolina Thank god your reply solved my problem like magic. May God bless you.

Answer (score 13):

For Arch-linux users:
I had to un-install the grml-zsh-config package and reboot:
`yay -Rncs grml-zsh-config`

Comment: Thanks, saved me! Reboot is not necessary, though. Just start a new shell session (call "zsh" or restart terminal).

Comment: This is golden.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was my fix.