# Why do you need to source .zshrc for every new shell in iTerm?

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, iterm

I've used Iterm2 with zsh everyday for the past 3 years, but I got a new computer and had to set it up again. The problem is that when I run `~/.zshrc` it works fine, but I have to do it on every new terminal window I open. Not a good experience.

I noticed that I don't have any `bashrc`, `bash_profile`, or `profile` (dot)files on my new machine.

Here's the code in `~/.zshrc`:

```
export ZSH=/Users/healy/.oh-my-zsh
plugins=(
  git
)
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
DEFAULT_USER=healy
```

Again, it works perfectly (and as expected), but only after I run the source command, and that shouldn't be the case.

[image]

Comment: You probably didn't change your default shell : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191780/how-do-i-configure-my-terminal-app-with-bash-and-iterm2-with-zshell-and-oh-my-zs

Comment: @nevets1219 If that were the case, sourcing a Zsh configuration file would almost certainly cause an error. (Although I'm assuming that `zsh-autosuggestions.zsh` contains *something* that `bash` couldn't interpret properly.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure your export/source are added after the plugins in your zshrc, as stated in this post:
[oh-my-zsh config file not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682456/oh-my-zsh-config-file-not-loading/15882090#15882090)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was the solution I came to as well.

Answer (score 20):

On starting a new shell just run the command `source ~/.zshrc` by configuring in the

**Preferences** -> **Profiles** -> **Select Default Profile**(default profile will be starred) -> **General** -> **Command** -> Select **Login Shell** -> **Send text at start:**

Enter the value `source ~/.zshrc`.

You may add `source ~/.zshrc; clear` in case you need to clear the screen contents after executing the command.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and changing the `Shells Open with` option fixed this for me.

To get here:

- Open Preferences for Terminal
- Select the General Tab
- Change Sells open with from `Default login shell` to Command (complete path) with the `/bin/zsh` in the input box.

Screeshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `oh-my-zsh` is not loaded because the line was comment out.

```
# IT'S WRONG! NEED TO UNCOMMENT
# export ZSH=/Users/$(whoami)/.oh-my-zsh
```

Though this question is not due to the same "comment out" obviously, I came to a conclusion that, if you need to `source ~/.zshrc` every time opening a shell instance, **there should be some issue with your `.zshrc`, 
and check `oh-my-zsh` and `antigen`(maybe) work fine.**

Answer (score 1):

On 11.2.1 with Terminal 2.11, assuming you have already created .zshrc in your home directory, launch Terminal and select Terminal >> Preferences >> Profiles >> Shell

Under "Startup" check "Run command:" and input `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using the default Mac terminal. I'm in the OSX Sonoma which has zsh as the default shell. To fix the autocomplete I:

1. `CMD+,`
2. Click `Profile` at the top menu
3. Click the `Shell` submenu
4. Check the box `[X] Run command: source ~/.zshrc`
5. Quick Terminal and relaunch

Probably the Mac default zsh is not loading .oh-my-zsh?
Is there a way to tell the default zsh to use `.oh-my-zsh` when terminal opens? Is my solution the way of doing this?

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

for me,It works like this.
Profiles 》Open Profiles 》Select “Edit Profiles” 》Profiles 》General
and put "source ~/.zsh" into Send text at start textfield.

Comment: changing the Shells Open with option is a better Idea. you can find the steps in the above answers. cheers