# iTerm2 startup command overwritten by user input, is there are better way to source ~/.zschrc

Tags: zsh, iterm2, zshrc

Since OSX changed the default shell to zsh I have been unhappy with my iTerm2 setup.

Initially I noticed that my ~/.zschrc file was not being sourced when a new shell was opened.

Following the guidance here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115598/how-to-set-an-iterm2-startup-command

and here

[Why do you need to source .zshrc for every new shell in iTerm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689939/why-do-you-need-to-source-zshrc-for-every-new-shell-in-iterm)

It seemed like the solution add `source ~/.zscshrc` to the following

**Preferences** -> **Profiles** -> **Select Default Profile**(default profile will be starred) -> **General** -> **Command** -> Select **Login Shell** -> **Send text at start**:

I have been using this solution for many months now and regularly find it annoying and it fails.

When a new terminal is opened I often begin issuing commands.

For example sake assume I issue the command "remote" (alias for ssh'ing into a remote machine)

The command I issue often gets mangled with the  **Send text at start** command, breaking both the sourcing of the .zschrc and my command.

Here is some sample output of my opening a new termnal and trying to issue commands

```
Last login: Fri Jan 24 11:42:10 on ttys007
rsource ~/.zschrc
simon@Simons-MacBook-Pro ~ % rsource ~/.zschrc
zsh: command not found: rsource
xxxx@xxxxx-MacBook-Pro ~ % emote
```

Here you can see the "r" from my "remote" command has got mangled with the sourcing of the .zshrc file.

This happens frequently and on occasion many times in a row when I am busy with some urgent task.

Does anyone else suffer from this problem and is there a solution or better way I should be sourcing my ~/.zschrc file?

Comment: The file to be sourced automatically is `.zshrc`, not `.zschrc`.

Comment: not sure who got here first, but I can only mark the other response as accepted answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **interactive** Zsh sources the file $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc on startup, where ZDOTDIR defaults to your home directory. If you want to source a different file instead (in your case with name .zschrc), create a file ~/.zshrc with the content

```
. ~/.zschrc
```

Comment: I am not sure how I ended up with the .zschrc file name.. glad I asked though, it was killing me, funny thing is every time I went to edit the file I would type vim .zshrc and get annoyed because I thought zsh had named the file weird! stupid me for not checking.